# Visual Studio Code extension development problem with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tsc

[image]

as you see above, the building process never finishes and no extension host window appears.

the problem also exists when all extensions all disabled

but this problem doesn't exist when creating project with javascript (the problem is only with **typescript**)

the steps that I follow is from [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension)
and I also tried the hello world sample from [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/).
but none of them worked.

---

**EDIT:**

I tried to open extension development host window manually by `code --extensionDevelopmentPath="path/to/my/project"` and it worked.

- I think the issue is with some of vscode's configurations

possible fix: I should check the configurations such as `npm: watch`. but I don't know where are they and what should I do with them??

so any idea?

**EDIT 2:**

`task.json`

```json
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "never"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

`launch.json`

```json
// A launch configuration that compiles the extension and then opens it inside a new window
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension Tests",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
                "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test/suite/index"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/test/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        }
    ]
}
```

- then I noticed that if I comment out `"preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"` in `launch.json` file, the problem solves.

Comment: typescript needs to be transpiled to Javascript, so an extension always runs JavaScript

Comment: @rioV8 ok, I know that, typescript should be compiled to javascript. in my project typescript compiles successfully but the extension development host doesn't appear.

Comment: you say that a Javascript project works, there is no difference after Typescript compilation, what if you make it a Javascript project with the files after compilation

Comment: @rioV8 the [generator code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-code) creates the project and I think I don't need to do anything extra about it. but I will try what you said :)

Comment: @rioV8 please see edits

Comment: shouldn't you use `tcs --watch`

Comment: @rioV8 I don't know much about them but I saw this in `launch.json` - `"preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"`

Comment: and what is your `watch` script in `package.json`

Comment: @rioV8 please check the post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I caught the issue. that was because of the locale of my system that was set to `Persian` which typescript problem matcher couldn't recognize(Persian digits).

By setting system locale to English the problem solved and everything now works fine as expected.

[please see the issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43723)